# Diferencias entre invocaciones JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

Hace un tiempo me estuve preguntando la siguiente cuestión:

Cual es la diferencia entre:

- **`$(document.body)`**
- **`$('body')`**

Si me pudieran fundamentar, sería de gran ayuda.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Cuando haces la referencia a `$(document.body)` entregas directamente el elemento BODY al jquery. Mientras que cuando haces `$('body')` jquery tiene que buscar e interpretar la cadena (en este caso body) y encontrar el elemento.

Algunos sitios webs te explican como cambia el rendimiento de respuesta en distintos casos.

Teniendo el rendimiento mas rapido utilizando `$(document.body)` y el mas lento `$('body)`

[aqui](https://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-body-on-document-on/) puedes encontrar algunos ejemplos

Answer (score 5):

Realmente son lo mismo. Haciendo referencia mediante `document` haces referencia directamente al elemento dentro del DOM mientras que utilizando el selector `$('body')`, JQuery tendrá que interpretar que es la etiqueta `<body>` que se encuentra dentro de la página y por lo tanto este segundo selector será más lento.

Answer (score 3):

Como te ponen en otras respuestas: el resultado final va a ser el mismo (se seleccionará el elemento `body`) y una de las opciones (`document.body`) será más rápida que la otra (`"body"`).

Si nos ponemos un poco tiquismiquis, sí que existe una pequeña diferencia en versiones antiguas de jQuery: el contexto que se pasaba y en el que se ejecutaba el código de jQuery.

[`.context`](https://api.jquery.com/context/) está disponible en jQuery 1.x (a partir de 1.3) y 2.x, se marcó como obsoleto en la versión 1.10, y fue eliminado completamente en la versión 3.0. Con ese método se puede ver el contexto del nodo DOM que se le pasó originalmente a `jQuery()`; si ninguno se pasa, entonces el contexto seguramente sea `document`.

Si se usara `.context`, sí que habría una diferencia entre hacer `$(document.body)` y `$("body")`, porque el contexto sería `body` y `#document` respectivamente y no son lo mismo (p.e. se pueden añadir elementos a `body` pero no a `document`).

Ejemplo usando `context` con `$(document.body)`:

```js
var body = $(document.body);
var h1 = $("<h1>Encabezado</h1>")[0];
body.context.append(h1);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Ejemplo usando `context` con `$("body")`:

```js
var body = $("body");
var h1 = $("<h1>Encabezado</h1>")[0];
body.context.append(h1);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```